# Is there a way to cast a generic enum value to an UInt64 value without allocating?

Tags: c#, performance, memory, enums, garbage-collection

I want to have a fast generic way of checking if an enum value that is marked with the `FlagsAttribute` is valid. To do this, I created a class called `EnumInfo<T>` that calculates the flags pattern in its static constructor by bitwise ORing all the different values of the enum. The `IsValidFlagsValue` method then simply checks the provided value by performing a bitwise AND compare with the flags pattern.

Consider the following C# code

```cs
// This code requires C# 7.3
public static class EnumInfo<T> where T : Enum, IConvertible
{
    // This field is calculated in the static constructor
    public static readonly ulong FlagsPattern; 

    public static bool IsValidFlagsValue(this T enumValue)
    {
        // The actual problem is here: ToUInt64 allocates (because of internal boxing?)
        var convertedUInt64Value = enumValue.ToUInt64(null);
        return (FlagsPattern & convertedUInt64Value) == convertedUInt64Value;
    }
}
```

**My actual problem is the following**: to reuse this code, I convert the enum values to type `ulong`. However, `enumValue.ToUInt64(null)` internally allocates 24 Bytes, as one can see in the following benchmark (performed with [BenchmarkDotNet](https://benchmarkdotnet.org/)):

```cs
public class ToUInt64Benchmark
{
    public IConvertible FlagsValue = 
        BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Instance;

    [Benchmark]
    public ulong EnumToUInt64() => FlagsValue.ToUInt64(null);
}
```

[image: BenchmarkDotNet results]

**Is there currently any way to avoid this allocation?** I tried to use unsafe code, but I cannot get the address of an generic value (i.e. `&enumValue` is not working). Is there maybe another way of doing this that I haven't thought of?

Thanks for your help in advance.

Comment: Restrict the generic to `struct, Enum` (no need for IConvertible) and then *maybe* use `Unsafe` (the class not the keyword). Also seen the project Enums.net. He uses a cool trick to cast enums to integrals, however it uses fody (il rewriting) to generate the body of that method

Comment: @pinkfloydx33 you are my hero! See my answer for details.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As [pinkfloydx33](https://stackoverflow.com/users/491907/pinkfloydx33) pointed out in the comments of this questions, there is a class called `Unsafe` in the [System.Runtime.CompilerServices.Unsafe](https://www.nuget.org/packages/System.Runtime.CompilerServices.Unsafe) NuGet package. With it, you can cast to ulong in an unsafe manner which does not allocate. If we modify the benchmark class from my question like the following:

```cs
public class ToUInt64Benchmark
{
    public BindingFlags FlagsValue = BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Instance;

    public IConvertible FlagsValueAsConvertible;

    public ToUInt64Benchmark() => FlagsValueAsConvertible = FlagsValue;

    [Benchmark(Baseline = true)]
    public ulong EnumToUInt64() => FlagsValueAsConvertible.ToUInt64(null);

    [Benchmark]
    public ulong UnsafeEnumToUInt64() => ConvertUnsafe(FlagsValue);

    private static unsafe ulong ConvertUnsafe<T>(T enumValue) where T : struct, Enum
    {
        var pointer = (ulong*)Unsafe.AsPointer(ref enumValue);
        return *pointer;
    }
}
```

...this leads to the following results:

[image: Benchmark Results with unsafe code]

It is way faster (only 10% of the execution time of `ToUInt64` in .NET Core 2.2 on my Surface Pro 4) and, most importantly, it does not allocate.

Please be sure to add the `AllowUnsafeBlocks` tag to your csproj file to allow the compilation of unsafe code. You cannot run this code on partially trusted platforms (like e.g. Silverlight). Here is the structure of my csproj file.

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">
  <PropertyGroup>
    <OutputType>Exe</OutputType>
    <TargetFrameworks>netcoreapp2.2;net472</TargetFrameworks>
    <DebugType>portable</DebugType>
    <PlatformTarget>x64</PlatformTarget>
    <LangVersion>7.3</LangVersion>
    <AllowUnsafeBlocks>true</AllowUnsafeBlocks>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="BenchmarkDotNet" Version="0.11.3" />
    <PackageReference Include="System.Runtime.CompilerServices.Unsafe" Version="4.5.2" />
  </ItemGroup>
</Project>
```

#### Update 2018-12-26 17:00 UTC

As [pinkfloydx33](https://stackoverflow.com/users/491907/pinkfloydx33) pointed out correctly in the comments (once again), the code can be simplified by using `Unsafe.As`:

```cs
public class ToUInt64Benchmark
{
    // Other members omitted for brevity's sake
    [Benchmark]
    public ulong UnsafeEnumToUInt64() => ConvertUnsafe(FlagsValue);

    private static ulong ConvertUnsafe<T>(T enumValue) where T : struct, Enum => 
        Unsafe.As<T, ulong>(ref enumValue);
}
```

This has no implications on the performance, but it does not require the `AllowUnsafeBlocks` tag in the csproj file.

Comment: can you just use `Unsafe.As` instead of the pointer stuff? Then you don't even need unsafe blocks. See second overload here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.runtime.compilerservices.unsafe.as?view=dotnet-plat-ext-2.1#System_Runtime_CompilerServices_Unsafe_As__2___0__

Comment: @pinkfloydx33 You are right once again, I've updated the answer.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot avoid boxing **and** use interfaces at the same time.  Boxing comes because you call an interface method on your `enumValue`.

If you are desperate to avoid the extra allocation - forget about interfaces.  High performance is not a close friend with perfect OO design.

Comment: I have to disagree: in `EnumInfo<T>`, I'm not calling `ToUInt64` on an interface type, but on a generic type. This does not involve a virtual call. You can argue that I call `ToUInt64` in the benchmark class, but notice that I cast to `IConvertible` in the constructor before the benchmark starts - thus it is not part of the measurement (I don't care how long this call takes, my point is that this call allocates 24 Bytes internally). You can learn more about how generics are processed by the JIT compiler in this video: https://youtu.be/7GTpwgsmHgU?t=1680

Comment: If you look at the implementation of `IConvertible.ToUInt64` of the `Enum` class, then you'll see that `GetValue` is called which boxes the value: https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/enum.cs,1006

Comment: Well, thanks for the links, but I still stand that you should get rid of the abstraction if you seek to avoid this extra allocation.

Comment: Nick, I posted another answer where I used the `Unsafe` class that pinkfloydx33 pointed me to in the comments. As you can see, it's fast and doesn't allocate. Object-Oriented design does not necessarily contradict with high-performance.